# Get all elements contained in document and their current values using jquery or any preferred library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to grab the entire DOM from a page using

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

but I noticed that it does not get the current values for any `inputs`, `textareas`, `selects`, etc...

Is there a way that I can grab their current values as well? essentially I want to take a snapshot of the page in its current state.

I have looked at `.each` and `.serialize` in JQuery, but it seems like both are not ideal solutions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First move the values of all form inputs to the `value` attribute :

```
$(':input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('value', this.value);
});
```

Then use your code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
// Or the jQuery way:
$('html').html()
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4xGxL/)

Comment: very smart.. I cant believe i didnt think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to select all the elements contained on the DOM through jQuery

```
 $(document).Ready(function(){
 //select all the document in the DOM
  $("*");
 });
```

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand the question at all. (and it has other problems anyway...)

Comment: Who upvoted the answer? it doesn't answer the question at all! and even have syantx error which throws `ReferenceError`